# Flash was "not designed to function across LANs". Any workarounds?

Tags: network-shares, lan, flash-cs6

See: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/problems-using-flash-authoring-across.html

> **Issue**
>
> When using Adobe Flash across a local area network (LAN) and networked
>   drives/folders, you may experience any of the following problems:"
>
> - Flash crashes while performing a test movie on FLA files located on a networked drive or folder.
> - FLA files get corrupted when opening from or saving to networked drives or folder.
> - Flash does not reflect changes in custom class after compiling.
> - Flash, Flash Video Encoder, or Adobe Media Encodercrashes or corrupts Flash Video (FLV) files while encoding source located on
>     networked drives or folder.
> - Flash Video Encoder or Adobe Media Encoder crashes or corrupts FLV files where the output folder is a networked drive or folder.
> - Published Flash Player (SWF) files and projectors are unable to load content located on networked drives or folder.
> - More than one instance of a SWF or Projector on client machines cannot play back FLV files located on a networked drive or folder.
>
> **Reason**
>
> The Adobe Flash IDE, FLV Encoder, Adobe Media Encoderand Flash Player
>   were not designed to function across LANs.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Use of Flash files across local networks is not supported in any
>   context. Published content should access data through a web server.
>   All file sources should be opened and saved on the local system. Using
>   Flash in such a scenario for project collaboration or content
>   deployment is highly discouraged and may corrupt your source files.
>
> If you need to work in a collaborative environment or store source
>   files on a server, use the project panel and/or a third-party version
>   control system.

SERIOUSLY?  I cannot work on files located on a mapped network drive?  How did they mess that one up?  Does the Flash IDE really open the source file and wipe it clean to do the saving, rather than saving a copy first then replacing it as an atomic file system operation?  How hard would it be for them make a dummy temporary file for saving then issue a MOVE command?

Any workarounds for this, like something that can make a network drive as stable as a local drive, like some kind of automatic local caching and synching?

Comment: As this forum discusses, http://forums.adobe.com/message/4689993, it's been a problem since Flash CS5, and many people feel that it's truly an unacceptable "design". "Are you aware that in the modern world EVERY company has a policy to save files over a network? For most developers it's not a choice of saving locally, it's just not an option. We are forced to use networkdrives, and if I may say so, I totally agree we should! Come on Adobe, this is 2011 you know! And saying in your technote (from 2009!) that we just have to use a third-party version control system is totally ridiculous!"

Comment: It worked for days, and suddenly this one time, it didn't work. The drive was connected and accessible. Saving progress halted at 1%. Program didn't freeze, but saving progress is a "modal dialog", so it blocked me from interacting with Flash. I was helpless, sitting there watching an otherwise fine process taunt me. After 10 minutes, it finally displayed a crash message, and my files were corrupt. I tried renaming the FLA to ZIP and opened it in WinRAR and chose the repair archive function. It repaired the file successfully, but Flash CS6 still complains of an "Unexpected File Format".